# Sum of Squares in Randomized Complete Block design

Tags: anova, sums-of-squares, blocking

I'm interested in the *Randomized Complete Block design* (RCB) with

- three treatments, which I call $A$, $B$, and $C$,
- and four blocks ($b=4$):
  \begin{align}
  \textrm{block 1: } (y_{A,1}; y_{C,1}; y_{B,1}) &\quad \quad \textrm{block 2: } (y_{B,2}; y_{C,2}; y_{A,2}) \\ 
  \textrm{block 3: } (y_{C,3}; y_{A,3}; y_{B,3})&\quad \quad \textrm{block 4: } (y_{A,4}; y_{C,4}; y_{B,4})\\ 
  \end{align} 
  where the $y$-values are the result of the experiment, their first index is the treatment index and the second index is the block index.
- without repetition of any experiment.

Furthermore, I consider the two *Helmert contrasts*

- $C_1 = A - B$, so the contrast vector reads $(a_1; a_2; a_3) = (1; -1; 0)$
- $C_2 = \frac{A}{2} + \frac{B}{2} - C$, so the contrast vector reads $(a_1; a_2; a_3) = (\frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{2}; -1)$

The *contrast Sum of Squares* (SS) of the treatments is given by 
$$SS(Trt) = \frac{\left(\sum_i a_i \bar y_{i\bullet}\right)^2}{\sum_i a_i^2} = \frac{(\bar y_{A\bullet} - \bar y_{B\bullet})^2}{2} + \frac{\frac{\bar y_{A\bullet}}{2} + \frac{\bar y_{B\bullet}}{2} - \bar y_{C\bullet} }{3/2}$$
Therefore, I need to find the $T\times B$ interaction to get the proper $F$-test $$ F = \frac{MS(Trt)}{MS(T\times B)}$$
where the MS are the *mean squares* (so just the SS divided by the degree of freedom).

However, I found that 
\begin{align}
SS(T \times B) &= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{b=1}^4 \left[(y_{A,b} - y_{B,b}) - (\bar y_{A\bullet} - \bar y_{B\bullet}) \right]^2  \\
&+ \frac{2}{3} \sum_{b=1}^4 \left[
\left(\frac{y_{A,b}}{2} + \frac{y_{B,b}}{2} - y_{C,b} \right) - 
\left(\frac{\bar y_{A\bullet}}{2} + \frac{\bar y_{B\bullet}}{2} - \bar y_{C\bullet} \right) \right]^2
\end{align}
This is a simple formula, however, how is it obtained? For me it looks like this is the *within treatment SS* and that the decomposition
$$SS(within \; Trt) = SS(between \; Blocks) + SS(T\times B)$$
has been "forgotten".